# Porque continuo tendo acesso ao estado atual do objeto neste caso? [EXEMPLO C#]

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, lista, construtor, collection

Uma dúvida bem básica, mas que está bugando a minha cabeça.

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

Uma classe que recebe uma lista como parâmetro no construtor:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
   IList<int> Items;

   public MinhaClasse(IList<int> Items)
   {
      this.Items = Items;
   }

   // Aqui eu tenho um método que manipula a propriedade Items
   public void MeuMetodo()
   {
       Items[0] = 1+1;
   }

}
```

Quando vou instanciar a classe, eu crio a lista, passo ela como parametro e chamo o "`MeuMetodo()`" que altera o valor do primeiro Item da minha lista de '0' para '2':

```
IList<int> items = new List<int>(){ 0 };

GildedRose app = new GildedRose(items);
app.MeuMetodo();

// A minha dúvida acontece aqui, pois continuo tendo acesso a lista de items, mas no novo estado, após a alteração pelo método da minha classe
Console.WriteLine(items[0]); // Essa linha imprime o valor '2' e não o valor '0' que é o valor atual da minha lista criada aqui
```

Para ter acesso ao valor '2' eu não teria que criar um "`Get`" dentro da "`MinhaClasse`" para retornar a propriedade "Items"? Porque continuou tendo acesso ao mesmo valor da minha propriedade da classe após chamar o "`MeuMetodo()`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pense assim: quando você cria um objeto, como essa lista, você recebe de volta uma referência a ele, que permite acessá-lo e manipulá-lo. No seu exemplo, a variável `itens` é quem guarda referência da lista recém-criada. Essa variável foi criada em determinado escopo, e sempre será acessível a partir desse escopo – como o seu exemplo mostra.

Ao criar a instância da sua classe, o que você passa ao construtor é essa referência. O construtor recebe a referência e guarda uma cópia dela num membro privado da sua classe. E é essa cópia privada da referência que não pode ser acessada de fora da classe (justamente porque é privada; se não fosse, poderia ser acessada via `app.Items`).

Parece que você está confuso porque está achando que seu código manipula diretamente "a lista". Mas não. "A lista" (ou "o objeto", "a instância" do tipo `List`) é uma coisa que existe na memória e, em C#, não é acessada diretamente, apenas por meio de referências. As referências é que estão sujeitas às regras da linguagem, como os modificadores de acesso das classes (`private`, `public` etc.). E o que tem no seu código são duas referências – uma fora da classe, outra dentro da classe. A da classe só pode ser acessada de dentro de objetos daquela classe. A de fora não tem restrições, está sujeita apenas às regras de visibilidade de escopo. Ambas manipulam o mesmo objeto, mas são referências diferentes, com regras de acesso diferentes.

Comment: Matou! Muito obrigado!!